# how to move mouse to specific point with keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors and on one I keep iTerm and vscode in fullscreen mode. I have shortcut keys via Karabiner to swich between the two. The problem is the other monitor has a few other apps not in full screen so I can monitor them. Like Mail, Spotify, Calendar etc.
I would like to be able to hit a shortcut and have my mouse placed on Spotify.

Bonus points if this can be done with multiple Chrome windows pointing to different websites.

Comment: could you rephrase your question to: "how to move mouse to specific point with keyboard shortcut"
So that it could help other people that have the same question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is possible, you can write it in **python**.

- you can make a shortcut that opens **python** script.
- or make it run continuously and when certain buttons are pressed move mouse to X and Y

I would recommend ***pyautogui*** - pip install pyautogui - https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui

function - ***moveTo()*** - Can move mouse by giving it X and Y coords.